# Google app Engine Application error

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to run the guestbook application https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating but getting error:

Error screenshot at the url http://goo.gl/rw0dnR

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection timed out
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:741]
```

I tried it on Eclipse. In Eclipse I click Run menu and then "Debug As"->"Web application". The error popup says:

> Problem Occurred: 'Launching Guestbook' has encountered a
>   problem.Cannot connect to VM. (Cannot connect to VM
>   com.sun.jdi.connect.TransportTimeoutException)

Could anyone help me troubleshhot.

The code is:

```
package guestbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine and it evidently compiles without error.  The problem appears to be rather low down in the run time environment of Eclipse, the AppEngine development environment or the Jetty web application server.

I suggest uninstalling and re-installing Eclipse and the AppEngine SDK, or better still try with another computer.

Is another process listening on port 8888?  On Windows use netstat -an at a command prompt to check.

You could try another port number.  In Eclipse select Run, Debug Configurations..., your project name, Server.  Change from 8888 and try again.

To prove that Eclipse is not the problem, temporarily use a fresh copy in a spare directory.  Get it from from [Eclipse Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), selecting "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and the appropriate 32 bit or 64 bit version.  Add both the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started) and [App Engine Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing) using the Eclipse Help -> Install new software... options, working with https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3 as the available software site.

Comment: I installed AppEngine SDK new version. Then tried. I got the same error. I do not have any other pc and so need to troubleshoot on it. Currently installed software on my pc are at http://goo.gl/1IjljX

Comment: Edited answer to include port availability.  If that's the problem, the error messages were not very helpful about it.

Comment: I went to Run, Debug Configurations, project name and changed port from 8888 to 8891 and also tried with 'use unused port' but still I get the same error.

Comment: Try installing a new copy of Eclipse in a temporary directory as added above and try again.  Be sure to have enough free space in the filesystem.